# Replace None in pandas data frame with Null

Tags: python, pandas, nullable, nonetype

I have a pandas dataframe and I am getting None for many values. I need to write it to SQL server DB and want to update it with Null. How can i do that?

I cannot use df.to_sql to write to DB, it is very slow. So I use pymsql. I convert the dataframe values as a tuple and form a sql insert statement. Hence i cannot have None, Nan, NAT etc. need to even clear it before writing to tuple.

```
self.sqlconn = pymssql.connect(server=self.server, user=self.username, password=self.password,database=self.database)

code for writing to sql db

cursor = self.sqlconn.cursor()
            for i in sql_dataframe.values:
                query = 'insert into ' + table_name + ' (' + ','.join(sql_dataframe.columns) + ') values ' + str(
                    tuple(i))
```

Comment: to clarify:- i am looking for NULL. not 'NULL' , 'NaN','None',NaN etc.

Comment: The SQL connector should do that conversion automatically.  Python's `None` and SQL's `NULL` are the same concept.   Have you tried it?

Comment: Pandas uses  None or NaN or NaT(in datetimelike) as Null in DB. So if you send those value, your DB should understand it(df.to_sql)

Comment: NaN could cause problems, but None will be Null.

Comment: https://realpython.com/null-in-python/

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel i cannot use df.To_sql because it is very slow. I am using the pymssql.connect(server=self.server, user=self.username, password=self.password,
                                       database=self.database)
and the inserts are done by creating  a query and passing using a cursor.

            

for i in sql_dataframe.values:
                query = 'insert into ' + table_name + ' (' + ','.join(sql_dataframe.columns) + ') values ' + str( tuple(i))
hence i cannot have the None and kind esp with smallints and all
                cursor.execute(query)

Answer (score 0):

try replacing None with explicit NULLs

```
df['col'] = df['col'].fillna('NULL')
```

Comment: i need NULL not 'NULL' string value.

Comment: I wonder, if this 'NULL' would be recoginze by some Database Management System as a String.

Comment: if 'NULL'  is passed, then it is a string. If NULL is passed then it is treated as NULL- it can go in string, int, small int and any sort of thing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).